# Why mdfind do not work for Chinese character?

Tags: macos

`mdfind` sometimes do not work for Chinese character.

#### Question Repeat

```
cd ~/Desktop
print "打字笔记\naabb" > test.md
```

- English character

execute

```
mdfind -onlyin ~/Desktop 'kMDItemContentType == "net.daringfireball.markdown" && kMDItemTextContent == "*aa*"'
```

got

`/path/to/test.md`

- Chinese character

execute

```
mdfind -onlyin ~/Desktop 'kMDItemContentType == "net.daringfireball.markdown" && kMDItemTextContent == "*工作*"'
```

got

`nothing`

#### Effort

I searched `mdfind` usage and tutorial, but could not find the reason